# C# Implicit conversion confusion with generics

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

Why do I get this error from my code?

> `OtaqGetAllRq` cannot be used as type parameter ... There is no implicit reference conversion from `OtaqGetAllRq` to `CrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM>`

This is the code in question:

```
public class OtaqGetAllRq : CrudGetAllRequestBase<OtaqAxtarishVM>
{
}

public class CrudGetAllRequestBase<TSearchCriteria> : AxtarishRequestBase<TSearchCriteria>
    where TSearchCriteria : BaseAxtarishVM, new()
{
    public CrudGetAllRequestBase()
    { 
    }
}

public class AxtarishRequestBase<TSearchCriteria> : RequestBase
    where TSearchCriteria : BaseAxtarishVM, new()
{
    public AxtarishRequestBase()
    {
        SearhCriteria = new TSearchCriteria();
    }

    public TSearchCriteria? SearhCriteria { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RequestBase
{
}

public class BaseAxtarishVM : BaseVM
{
    public BaseAxtarishVM()
    { 
    }

    public virtual string? ModuleId { get; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseVM : IBaseVM
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<THamisiniGetirRq> : TbcCoreDataComponentBase
    where THamisiniGetirRq : CrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM>
{ 
}

public class OtaqMainBase2 : Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<OtaqGetAllRq>
{
    public OtaqMainBase2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: Because `CrudGetAllRequestBase<OtaqAxtarishVM>` and `CrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM>` are two different classes and generic classes can not be covariance.

Comment: @sweeper edited. Last line is problematic one.

Comment: @shingo thanks. could you pls help with code transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `CrudGetAllRequestBase<OtaqAxtarishVM>` and `CrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM>` are two different classes, so they cannot be converted to each other, though `OtaqAxtarishVM` is derived from `BaseAxtarishVM`.

You have 3 choices:

**1. Abstracting an interface from the class**

Interfaces can be covariance, that means you can cast `ICrudGetAllRequestBase<OtaqAxtarishVM>` to `ICrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM>`.

```
public interface ICrudGetAllRequestBase<out TSearchCriteria>
    where TSearchCriteria : BaseAxtarishVM { }

public class CrudGetAllRequestBase<TSearchCriteria> : AxtarishRequestBase<TSearchCriteria>,
    ICrudGetAllRequestBase<TSearchCriteria>
    where TSearchCriteria : BaseAxtarishVM, new() { }

public abstract class Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<THamisiniGetirRq> : 
    TbcCoreDataComponentBase
    where THamisiniGetirRq : ICrudGetAllRequestBase<BaseAxtarishVM> { }

public class OtaqMainBase2 : Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<OtaqGetAllRq> { }
```

**2. Applying a base non-generic class constraint**

`OtaqGetAllRq` is derived from `RequestBase`, so don't worry about generic parameters.

```
public abstract class Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<THamisiniGetirRq> : TbcCoreDataComponentBase
    where THamisiniGetirRq : RequestBase { }

public class OtaqMainBase2 : Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<OtaqGetAllRq> { }
```

**3. Adding a generic parameter**

It seems a little cumbersome, but method 1 and 2 have their limits, this always works.

```
public abstract class Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<THamisiniGetirRq, TSearchCriteria> : TbcCoreDataComponentBase
    where THamisiniGetirRq : CrudGetAllRequestBase<TSearchCriteria>
    where TSearchCriteria : BaseAxtarishVM, new() { }

public class OtaqMainBase2 : Tbc2DepCrudAsPopupNsBase<OtaqGetAllRq, OtaqAxtarishVM> { }
```